# pip installing MySQL-python fails to install

Tags: python, mysql

When I try to do `pip install MySQL-python`, it throws these errors.

```sh
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: 'C:\Users\Pavan P\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Pavan P\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-di8y9ty8\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Pavan P\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-di8y9ty8\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Pavan P\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hhq0wpgs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Pavan P\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\MySQL-python'
        cwd: C:\Users\Pavan P\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-di8y9ty8\MySQL-python\
   Complete output (29 lines):
   running install
   running build
   running build_py
   creating build
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
   copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
   copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
   copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
   copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
   copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
   copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
   copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
   copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
   copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
   copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
   copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
   copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
   copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
   copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
   running build_ext
   building '_mysql' extension
   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
   _mysql.c
   _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
   error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
   ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Pavan P\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Pavan P\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-di8y9ty8\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Pavan P\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-di8y9ty8\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Pavan P\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hhq0wpgs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Pavan P\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\MySQL-python' Check the logs for full command output.
```

what should I do?

Comment: You can increase the chances of better answers by giving details of your systems e.g. os, and Python version

Answer (score 1):

You can install the other options which are the same,

```
pip install pymysql
```

or

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

or

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```